# How to do recursive copy of files and directories using ant task

Tags: ant

Ant has inbuilt Copy task to copy multiple files.
I tried to define following target in build.xml file

```
 <target name="copyFile">
        <copy todir="../CHECK">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <patternset id="AllFiles">
                    <include name="*"/>
                </patternset>
        </fileset>
        </copy>
   </target>
```

It is copying files and directories. However content within directories is not copied, instead directories are copied as empty to destination "../CHECK". Does Ant copy task provides capability to do recursive copy of files and directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer
name pattern in include should be "**" instead of "*". It does recursive copy of all contents

```
  <target name="copyFile">
            <copy todir="../CHECK">
                <fileset dir=".">
                    <patternset id="AllFiles">
                        <include name="**"/>
                    </patternset>
            </fileset>
            </copy>
       </target>
```